# Looking at two versions of Fundamental Abelian groups theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> 1. $G$ is a finite abelian group. Then it can be expressed with a direct product of cylic groups with prime power order
> 2. $G$ is a finite abelian group with order $n$. Then it can be expressed as
>
> $$C_{r1} \times...\times C_{rk}$$
>
> where $r_1 |r_2|...|r_k$ and $r_1r_2...r_k=n$.

The first version gave me $6$ isomorphic cyclic direct products for a abelian group of order $600$. I was aksed of this in a problem.

However, I tried using the second theorem out of curiosity but all I could get is

> (600),(2,300),(5,120),(10.60),(2,2,150) as the possible $r_k$s.

Can anyone come up with the last set of factors?

Comment: Did you just randomly try options? You should look at the prime factorization of $600$, which is $2^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5^2$. Clearly, at most there are $3$ factors. To find those combinations, check how many ways you can spread each prime power. For $2$, you have $(1,1,8)$, $(1,2,4)$ and $(2,2,2)$; for $3$ you only have $(1,1,3)$ and for $5$ you have $(1,1,25)$ and $(1,5,5)$. Combine these $3 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 = 6$ options to get all factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to move from one decomposition to the other:
For the first method, I assume you found from $600=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5^2$
$$ C_8\times C_3\times C_{25},\quad C_2\times C_4\times C_3\times C_{25},\quad C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_3\times C_{25},\\
 C_8\times C_3\times C_{5}\times C_5,\quad C_2\times C_4\times C_3\times  C_{5}\times C_5,\quad C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_3\times  C_{5}\times C_5.$$
To obtain the corresponding decomposition of the second kind, for each $p$, pick a maximal factor and multiply over all $p$ to get one cyclic factor; then repeat with the remaining prime power groups. This way you get (in same order as above)
$$C_{600},\quad C_{300}\times C_2,\quad C_{300}\times C_2,\quad C_{150}\times C_2\times C_2,\\
C_{120}\times C_5,\quad C_{60}\times C_{10},\quad C_{30}\times C_{10}\times C_2. $$
To perfectly match the prescription, reverse the order of the factors.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it should be $(2,10,30)$.

Comment: Oh brilliant...was hard to find that one, thanks!